# JWT signatures in court

Tags: docusignapi

If we want to go for the JWT option on our website where we request the docusign signature on behalf of our clients, would this signature still be accepted in court and still be binding to the client?

Thanks,
Adrian.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Please upvote all answers that you find helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: Your question is conflating sending and signing roles, plus the authentication issues of a signer.

Details:

The OAuth JWT Grant enables an application to impersonate a user on a DocuSign account. The result of the JWT Grant flow is an access token that can be used to send an envelope (transaction) out for signing, manage envelopes, etc.

The access token can be used to provide a signing ceremony to the impersonated user or to some other signer on an envelope. This is *embedded signing*.

Anytime you enable embedded signing, your app needs to have a clear authentication process to ensure that the person who is offered the signing ceremony is who they say they are. If you're enabling anybody to sign as Sam Signer, then anybody will be able to forge Sam Signer's signature. (And Sam, even if he really did sign, will be able to claim that he didn't actually sign. This is called repudiation. Not good.)

To guard against forgery and prevent repudiation, it is important to authenticate the signer. Since most signers in the DocuSign system are not DocuSign users, the issues of signer authentication is independent of the type of OAuth used, or if any OAuth was used (the usual case.)

DocuSign offers many levels of signer authentication, built in, to prevent forgery and signature repudiation. Which authentication (and signing) method you choose to use for a particular transaction depends on the applicable laws, value of the transaction, threat level of forgery/repudiation, etc.

For example, many DocuSign transactions use an SMS message to authenticate the signer since the assumption is that only the real signer will have access to their cell phone. Others use KBA, knowledge based authentication. Others use [DocuSign's ID Verification](https://www.docusign.com/products/identify) which requires that the signer scan their driving license or passport to authenticate themselves. We can also have the signer authenticate via a live webcam conference (see [ID.now](https://www.idnow.io/docusign-idnow-launch-100-remote-qualified-electronic-signature-offer/)).

**Re: Is it accepted in court and binding on the client?**

Yes, eSignatures are accepted in court and are binding on clients. See the [DocuSign eSignature Legality Guide](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/legality/global) for more information. More importantly: you need to consult your own legal counsel to ensure that your eSignature project conforms to the applicable laws. DocuSign has been validated in court cases. But only your own legal counsel can tell you the applicable law.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Much appreciated.